# why with ios7 My stackViewController put this white line?

Tags: ios, ipad, nsstackview

[image]

Why there is this white space at bottom-left? it wasn't here on ios6 compiled version and i can't understand how to remove it. My nib file hasn't it (the top level view is large as you see (20 pixel left from the image) and controller side there isn't any trace of view's dimensions.

EDIT: i've already tried to put C_X solution on code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];


self.view.backgroundColor = [NVGlobals homeCellBackgroundColor];
// on the iPad, disable panning (because we're inside a stacked
// view controller
if (IS_IPAD) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.panEnabled = YES;

}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT:  PROBLEM SOLVED: I'm using a plugin called PSStackedView (https://github.com/steipete/PSStackedView/) and to use it correctly on iOS7 you must change  *viewRect* with bounds instead of application:

```
- (CGRect)viewRect {
// self.view.frame not used, it's wrong in viewWillAppear
CGRect viewRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
return viewRect;
```

}

Comment: It is issue of status bar in iOS 7 so you need to manage it in iOS 7.. There are many ways but you can also give top of Main view *(`self.view`)* **20** pixel.

Comment: At your navCon of rootViewCon.. self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548);

Answer (score 0):

This is because in iOS we have extended edges, you can set it  to UIRectEdgeNone.

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Then your view will not move up under the status bar.

Comment: @Alessio Crestani: This is available in ios7 and later. If your app supports ios check you should check the IOS version and use.

Comment: Have i to write it on the viewDidLoad of the top layer? because it didn't work.

Comment: @C_X i'm transitioning my app to ios7

Comment: If you are supproting both iOS6 and iOS 7 you can use deltas... Now If you are supporting only iOS 7 it will be fine to set this property in ViewDidLoadMethod after call to super

Comment: it doesn't work. I put it after super.viewDidLoad of the topView. And if you watch the screenshoot, you can see that the imageview is set without 20px from bottom.

Comment: Never use this syntax `super.viewDidLoad` for method, its acceptable for properties only... this is not the way you calling  method in Objective-c, `[super viewDidLoad]`;